# Editing Favorites Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, files

I am trying to edit an entry in the favorites located on the left-hand side of the Files window. Namely, I have moved my Dropbox directory to another drive. How can make sure that upon clicking the Dropbox in the favorites, I am taken to that new directory?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current "Dropbox" item in your menu does not work anymore, then delete it and recreate a new entry.

- Remove the current "Dropbox" bookmark by right-clicking and selecting "Remove".
- Create a new item by navigating into your current "Dropbox" folder. Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. This shortcut will automatically add an updated bookmark to the left bar. Alternatively, pull down the folder menu in the top bar and select "Add to bookmarks".